# jQuery parse HTML element and get it's inner HTML

Tags: jquery

I have a table in HTML with table rows, but some elements have an `<span>` elements inside, so i want to get the inner html of that span.

I have an array with all `<tr>` elements (not jQuery Objects, because I get it from the DataTables plugin API), so I have this code:

```
if (data[i+1].includes("span")) {
     var label = $.parseHTML(data[i+1]);
     // editFormInputs.eq(i).val(label.first().html());
} else {
    editFormInputs.eq(i).val(data[i+1]);
}
```

So the problem is on the commented line. I tried to convert the html to jQuery element with `parseHTML()`, which returns an array. This works fine, but when I try to get the first element of the array with the `first()` function it gives me an error `first() is not a function`, so what I am doing wrong? Thanks.

Comment: Please post some code which you have tried so far. So others can point you in right direction

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`parseHTML`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseHTML/) is one of the rare jQuery functions that doesn't give you a jQuery object; it gives you an array:

> `jQuery.parseHTML( data [, context ] [, keepScripts ] )`
>
> Returns: **`Array`**
>
> Description: Parses a string into an **array** of DOM nodes.

*(my emphasis)*

So:

```
editFormInputs.eq(i).val($(label[0]).html());
```

Note that `label[0]` will be the `tr` element. It wasn't clear to me that you wanted the HTML of the `tr` element vs. one of its `span`s, but in any case, that's the reason for the error.

If you want the HTML of (say) the first `span` in the `tr`:

```
editFormInputs.eq(i).val($(label[0]).find("span").first().html());
```

Comment: Yes, it works fine now, thanks a lot! I thought that `parseHTML` returns an array of jQuery elements and not a regular Javascript array.

Comment: @EliasGarciaMariño: :-) Well, even if it did, `label.first()` would fail because regardless of what it contains (DOM elements vs. jQuery objects), the array `label` referred to won't have a `first` method.